# How do I add an 'onClick' event to a mapped data?

Tags: reactjs

```
        {data && data.map((data) => <Cards data={data} key={data._id} />)}
```

The code checks if there is data and of course if there is, it displays the card component.
I want to add a click event so I could know which of the list of cards retuned in particular is being clicked.
I've done this, it does not work.

```
{data && data.map((data) => <Cards onClick={click} data={data} key={data._id} />)}
```

and here is the click function

```
  const click = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log("clicked");
```

};

Comment: how is the click function defined ?

Comment: Could you please also include the click function? And is it showing any error?

Comment: Check it now, I have edited the question with the click function added. 
And It doesn't display any error it just doesn't do anything. I think the click event isn't firing.

Comment: It works now. I had to wrap the <Card/> component in a div and put the click event on the div. I guess you can not directly put it in a component.   <div onClick={click}><Card/></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo onClick and not onCLick

Edit:
You can wrap the `<Card/>` inside a `<div>` and add onClick to the div or inside the `<Card/>` component add onClick to the parent component and pass your click function as a prop

Comment: I'm sorry, I made the error here. the code doesn't work with ''onClick"

Comment: You can wrap the `<Card/>` inside a `<div>` and add onClick to the div or inside the `<Card/>` component add onClick to the parent component and pass your click function as a prop

Comment: Okay, let me try this!

Comment: It works! God bless you man! <3

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped if you could mark this as the answer would appreciate it